# How to convert a floating point into its hexadecimal representation in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I need help in converting an engineering decimal value (floating point) into its hexadecimal representation in VBA... The code below takes the integer part only and not the decimal. I would like to have the floating point represented in hex.

```
Sub float2hex()

'Declaring variables
 hexsimvalue As String, txdata As Double


    txdata = 100.25                                            
    hexsimvalue = Hex(txdata)                                 

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert decimal fractions to hexadecimal fractions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20650954/11683)

Comment: @GSerg, this is specific to vba

Comment: Yes, but you should be able to implement the algorithm in VBA.