# Decimal to Hexadecimal conversion of a number with fractional part, in python?

Tags: python

I want to change decimal with fraction to hexadecimal in python, I tried hex() function but works just for integer number

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do mention 3 important things in your question. 1st- sample of input, 2nd- sample of output and 3rd- your efforts in form of code. Thank you

Comment: It's unclear what you mean here: "decimal with fraction" could mean all sorts of different things. What form does the input data take? What Python type? An example or two would help clear things up. (Converting to hexadecimal could also have various meanings.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Python uses the float class to represent the real numbers.
>
> CPython implements float using C double type. The C double type
> usually implements IEEE 754 double-precision binary float, which is
> also called binary64.
>
> Python float uses 8 bytes (or 64 bits) to represent real numbers.
> Unlike the integer type, the float type uses a fixed number of bytes.
>
> Technically, Python uses 64 bits as follows:
>
> 1 bit for sign (positive or negative) 11 bits for exponent 1.5e-5 1.5
> x 10-5 (exponent is -5) the range is [-1022, 1023]. 52 bits for
> significant digits

quotes from this [site](https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-float/#:%7E:text=Python%20float%20uses%208%20bytes,a%20fixed%20number%20of%20bytes.)

```
Take integer part convert it to hexa decimal
```

And for fractional part use below algorithm:

1. Take a fractional part of the number
2. Multiply by 16
3. Convert integer part of the number to hexadecimal and remove it
4. Go to step 1

Finally join the integer and floating part together

please visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650954/how-to-convert-decimal-fractions-to-hexadecimal-fractions/20651123#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20this%20algorithm,hexadecimal%20and%20put%20it%20down) of stackoverflow for more details.

```
"""
Converts from float to hexadecimal
"""
def toHex(value:float):
    result = ""
    l = list()
    #converting to positive number and storing the - sign to the list
    if value < 0: 
        value = -value;
        l.append('-')

    ivalue = int(value)#represent the integer part
    fvalue = value - ivalue#represent the floating part
    
    l.append(hex(ivalue))#storing the hexadecimal representation of integer part
    l.append('.')

    #float is 8 bytes and so has at most 16 hexadecimal values
    for i in range(16):
        fvalue = fvalue * 16
        digit = int(fvalue)
        l.append(format(digit,'X'))
        fvalue -= digit#removing the integer part
        if fvalue == 0:
          break
    #converting the result to a string
    for v in l:
        result += str(v)

    return result;
    
    
    

print(toHex(3.141592653))
```

### Output:

```
$ python3 hexa.py 
0x3.243F6A85FD27
```

Comment: **format(digit,'x')** converts **digit** to **hexa** value without adding any '#' in front of it

Comment: Note that some floats will need more than 16 hex digits following the point. For example `x=1e-10` needs 22.