# Convert hex float to decimal and vice versa, non-exponential representation

Tags: python, floating-point, hex

I'm trying to convert non-integers to and from hexadecimal<->decimal representations. This is trivial for integers, but I can't get it to work like I want for non-integers.

I'm looking for the hex representation of the number, not a hex representation of its binary encoding.

I've gotten this far:

```py
float.fromhex('2a.0')     # prints "42.0" (number), fine
float(42.0).hex()           # prints "'0x1.5000000000000p+5'" (string), not fine
```

`float.hex()` returns a string holding a number in exponential representation. Is there a formatter that will convert to non-exponential representation? I want `'0x2a.0'`. Is this possible?

Comment: "I'm looking for the hex representation of the number, not a hex representation of its binary encoding." - you're *getting* a hex representation of the number, not a hex representation of its binary encoding. A hex representation of the binary encoding would look very different.

Comment: What is the purpose of 0x42.0 ? The leading 0x implies that hexadecimal values follow but they don't. Having said that if X == 42.0 then f'{0x{X:.1f}' will give you what you want

Comment: Why do you want `'0x42.0'` instead of `0x2a.0`?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71090865/18125313) help?

Comment: This is not a trivial problem.  Folks who haven't worked in assembler might not realize just how difficult it is even to convert "123.456" from binary to a decimal value.  You have to do it essentially like long division.

Comment: @user2357112 My attempts to google for the thing I wanted gave me either answers for integers or binary/hex representations of floats. I was clarifying what I wanted to avoid incorrectly being flagged as a duplicate. '0x42.0' was an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you actually want is to get `0x2a.0` back instead of `0x1.5000000000000p+5`?

Unfortunately, the [builtin format](https://www.askpython.com/python/string/python-format-function) specifiers don't support hexadecimal formatting of floating points. The [hex-function](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/hex.html) in your example doesn't support any arguments to e.g. suppress the scientific notation. I also couldn't find any library for this problem.

If you concern about performance, you may want to implement this in C. In this case the [C-implementation of float.hex](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/floatobject.c#L1236) may be a good thing to look at. Interestingly, it seems (to me) like they do extra work to perform the exponential shift but don't support a way to bypass it.

#### Edit:

I played around a bit and it's actually much easier to deal with the floating point number directly instead of messing around with the strings from `float.hex` (which was my original idea). Here is, what I'd come up with:

```py
def float_to_hex(number: float, precision: int = 6) -> str:
    if precision == 0:
        return hex(int(number))

    hex_int = hex(int(number * 16**precision))[2:]
    if len(hex_int) <= precision:
        hex_int = "0" * (precision - len(hex_int) + 1) + hex_int
    hex_float = f"{hex_int[:-precision]}.{hex_int[-precision:]}".rstrip("0")
    return f"0x{hex_float}"
```