# How to solve binary to decimal with fraction in c#? Using winform, Im trying to convert binary numbers into decimal. I used the input function

Tags: c#, winforms, binary, decimal, windows-forms-designer

```
if (binarybtn.Checked == true)
{
    int decVal = 0, baseVal = 1, rem;
    binarytxtbox.Text = textBox1.Text;

    int input = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

    while (input > 0)
    {
        rem     = input % 10;
        decVal  = decVal + rem * baseVal;
        input   = input / 10;
        baseVal = baseVal * 2;
    }

    decimaltxtbox.Text = Convert.ToString(decVal);

    ...
```

I tried using the input function, but it *does not accept* strings `"."`

Comment: Please, provide an *example* of the input and the desired result, e.g. input: `"10.1"`, output `"2.5"`.

Comment: Please provide more information about what you are trying to do. What is your input? Is it a binary number (10001110). Is it a base 10 number you want to convert to binary?

Comment: If you want to convert a binary input (`textBox1.Text`) to a Integer you can simply add the base to the call of [ToInt32(String, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?source=recommendations&view=net-7.0#system-convert-toint32(system-string-system-int32))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you right, you have a *binary* number with a *fractional part*, like

```
10.1 (binary)
```

and you want to convert it into a corresponding *decimal* number, in the case above it is

```
2.5 (decimal)
```

If it's your task, you can use

```
private static decimal BinaryToDecimal(string value, char decimalSeparator = '.') {
  value = value.Trim();

  int sign = value.StartsWith('-') ? -1 : 1;

  value = value.Trim('-');

  int index = value.IndexOf(decimalSeparator);

  string integerPart = index >= 0 ? value.Substring(0, index) : value;

  decimal result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(integerPart)
    ? 0
    : Convert.ToInt64(integerPart, 2);

  string fractionalPart = index >= 0 ? value.Substring(index + 1) : "";

  for (int i = 0; i < fractionalPart.Length; ++i)
    result += (decimal)(fractionalPart[i] - '0') / (1L << (i + 1));

  return sign * result;
}
```

Usage:

```
decimaltxtbox.Text = $"{BinaryToDecimal(binarytxtbox.Text)}";
```

Demo:

```
using System.Linq;

...

string[] tests = {
  "0",
  "-0",
  "100",
  "-100",
  "10.",
  "-10.",
  "1.1",
  "101.101",
  "-101.101",
  ".1011",
  "-.11011",
  "100.00",
  ".", // <- It seems, you treat it as a valid input
};

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"{test,10} => {BinaryToDecimal(test)}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

Output:

```
         0 => 0
        -0 => 0
       100 => 4
      -100 => -4
       10. => 2
      -10. => -2
       1.1 => 1.5
   101.101 => 5.625
  -101.101 => -5.625
     .1011 => 0.6875
   -.11011 => -0.84375
    100.00 => 4
         . => 0
```

If you are looking for *reverse* (i.e. from decimal to binary) conversion, have a look at

[How to convert decimal fractions to hexadecimal fractions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650954/how-to-convert-decimal-fractions-to-hexadecimal-fractions/20651123#20651123)

Comment: You answered exactly my problem! Thank u so much! I'm using this code for my Midterm project.

Comment: Hello sir, can I email you about my project? I really need help solving some problems on my code...

Comment: @John Allen: OK, but, please, remember it is *your midterm*: I'll try to help you with some problems, but it you who is supposed to implement the software. When stating problems, please, don't forget to start from *test examples*: what is the input, what is the desired output (behavior) and what is the actual one.