# I want to convert fractions of a binary into a decimal fraction, but my program keeps on giving wrong output

Tags: c#, arrays, binary, decimal, fractions

The formula for solving binary point into decimal point is... if `10.110` then: `1x10\*\*-1, 1x10\*\*-2, ...`
but my code is so messed idk... The output of this should be `.75`

```
        string a = "10.110";
        if (a.Contains('.'))
        {
            int i = a.IndexOf('.');
            string s = a.Substring(i + 1);
            char[] c = s.ToCharArray();
            int m = 0;

            while (m < c.Length)
            {
                int x = -1;
                int b = c[i] * (10 * x);
                int p = 0;
                p = b + b;
                Console.WriteLine(p);

                x = x + -1;
                m++;
            }
                
        }
```

```
The formula for solving binary point into decimal point is... if 10.110 then: 1x10**-1, 1x10**-2, ... but my code is so messed idk... The output of this should be .75
```

Comment: I think the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75530734/6196568) of your previous question can answer this question too, but you didn't attempt to understand it.

Comment: Your problems are: `c[i]` is a `char` and that's why `c[i] == '1' != 1`; if you treat `a` as a *binary* then `10 * x` is wrong, it should be `2 * x`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please, note that if `10.110` is *binary* (i.e. `radix = 2`) then its value is

```
10.110 (binary) == 2**1 + 2**-1 + 2**-2 == 2 + 0.5 + 0.25 == 2.75
```

if we ignore integer part, i.e. we have `.110` binary then

```
.110 (binary) == 2**-1 + 2**-2 = 0.5 + 0.25 == 0.75
```

In order to manipulate with these numbers *easily*, I suggest to *enumerate* all powers of `1`s in the given `value`:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> Factors(string value, char decimalSeparator = '.') {
  int pointAt = value.IndexOf(decimalSeparator);

  if (pointAt < 0)
    pointAt = value.Length; // we have an integer value

   for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i)
     if (value[i] == '1')
       yield return i < pointAt
         ? pointAt - i - 1
         : pointAt - i;
}
```

Then you can do whatever you like with that enumeration (with a little help of *Linq*):

```
using System.Linq;

...

string text = "10.110";

// Remark:  in the correct formula it should be 2, not 10
// I've kept "10" to demonstrate the Linq query
string fractionPartPowers = string.Join(", ", Factors(text)
  .Where(power => power < 0)  // fraction part only, no integer part
  .Select(power => $"1x10**{power}"));

Console.WriteLine(fractionPartPowers);

double fractionPart = Factors(text)
  .Where(power => power < 0) // fraction part only, no integer part
  .Sum(power => Math.Pow(2, power)); // note radix == 2

Console.WriteLine(fractionPart);
```

Output:

```
1x10**-1, 1x10**-2
0.75
```

**Edit:** your code corrected

```
//TODO: come up with a better name: what does "a" stand for?
string a = "10.110";

double total = 0.0;

int startAt = a.IndexOf('.');

// If we have a fractional part which starts from startAt
if (startAt >= 0)
  // for is more readable than while here; 
  // let's track index i within a and corresponding power
  for (int i = startAt + 1, power = -1; i < a.Length; ++i, --power) {
    // we ignore all but 1's
    if (a[i] != '1')
      continue;

    total += Math.Pow(2.0, power);

    // let's print powers
    Console.WrietLine(power);
  }

// 0.75
Console.Write(total);
```

Output:

```
-1
-2
0.75
```